# How to send and handle a json file in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

on serverside, i get a simple json file via REST with a lot of IDs, something like that:

```
[ {
"_id": "5825a49dasdasdasd8417c1b6d5",
}
"_id": "dfsdfsdf4960932218417c1b6d5",
}
"_id": "23434344960932218417c1b6d5",
},]
```

For that i have written in the main:

```
main.post('/..../add', Controller.addEvent);
```

In the Controller, i want to recieve the request and search in the mongodb for these ID's, because i need some informations about these IDs

```
exports.addEvent = function(req, res) {

    var collection = db.get().collection('events');
```

My question is, if someone send me over "localhost:8080/events/add" the given simple json file, how do i have to handle this json? i need the ID's and want to search with them.

Thanks for help!

----------ADDED------------

I am bit further now. In my controller i have the following function

```
exports.addevent = function(req, res) 
{ 
var ids = req.body; 
console.log(ids); 
}
```

Now i'm getting all IDs, which i have posted with "Postman" from chrome. 
The output in the console is:

```
[ { _id: '5825a49dasdasdasd8417c1b6d5' }, 
{ _id: 'dfsdfsdf4960932218417c1b6d5' }, 
{ _id: '23434344960932218417c1b6d5' } ]
```

How can i have every single ID?

Comment: Pretty sure no one is going to send anything on localhost

Comment: i have installed a local server, so that i can post via the ChromePlugin "POSTMAN" a json file.

Comment: use [Array.prototype.map()](https://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj8jYa046DQAhWMEbwKHZVyBO4QFggXMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fmap&usg=AFQjCNG-88X_4BP621jc1yLUJwBxSXgcxg&sig2=K3Ogc4qS2itaJG7Ho_gLkw&bvm=bv.138169073,d.dGc)

Comment: What did you try and where are you stuck? Did you use `find` ?

Comment: My problem is the handling with the json. 
How can i read the received json file, so that i can read call the ids.

If i call "http://localhost:8080/event/add" with the given json input, i don't know how to handle this received json

Comment: you basically want to send data as json to you rest controller ? right ?

Comment: Yes...i am bit further now. In my controller i have the following function

exports.addevent = function(req, res) {

        var ids = req.body;
        console.log(ids);
}

Now i'm getting all IDs, which i have posted with "Postman" from chrome.
The output in the console is:

[ { _id: '5825a49dasdasdasd8417c1b6d5' },
  { _id: 'dfsdfsdf4960932218417c1b6d5' },
  { _id: '23434344960932218417c1b6d5' } ]


How can i have every single ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the request is an object and not a string. That was the error :-/

```
        for(var i in ids) {
        console.log(ids[i]._id);
    }
```

and it works, now i can connect to the database and search for the id